# Amazon API- The request must contain the parameter Signature

Tags: c#, amazon-product-api

Whenever I try to perform a search I receive an unhandled SOAP Exception stating that the request must contain the Parameter Signature.

This happens when the following is executed:

```
ItemSearchResponse response = service.ItemSearch(request);

AWSECommerceService cs = new AWSECommerceService();

ItemSearchRequest request = new ItemSearchRequest();
request.SearchIndex = "Books";
request.Title = "asp.net";
request.ResponseGroup = new string[] { "small"};

ItemSearch search = new ItemSearch();
search.AssociateTag = "";
search.Request = new ItemSearchRequest[] { request };
search.AWSAccessKeyId = "";
search.Request = new ItemSearchRequest[] { request };
try
{
    ItemSearchResponse res = cs.ItemSearch(search);
    foreach (var item in res.Items[0].Item)
    {
        Response.Write(item.ItemAttributes.Title + "<br>");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Label1.Text = ex.Message;
}
```

I don’t really know how to troubleshoot the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Does `ItemSearchRequest` have a member `Signature`?

Comment: I don't have any idea of how to add Sigurature.If any one knows, it will be thankfull

Comment: This may help http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/HMACSignatures.html

Comment: Can u send me sample code, for authentication.